# Can anyone help me with Mathematical Methods Boaz book problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to reckon the preliminary test $\lim_{n\to \infty}{a_{n}}$ of series $\sum_{2}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n} n}{n - 1}$ ?  This problem was found in Cap 1 section 9 of book  Mathematical Methods from Boaz.

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate what a preliminary test means here?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot Shikhar Jaiswal, the preliminary test as defined in Boaz Book says that if $\lim_{n \to \infty}{a_{n}} \ne 0$ the series diverge. I don't know reckon limits of alternatings.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\left|\frac{(-1)^n n}{n-1}\right|=1$ thus the limit of $\frac{(-1)^n n}{n-1}$ can't be $0$ (in fact it has no limit).